# app is showing 3 tab in Simulator & iphone & only 2 tabs in Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, ios6.1

I am using storyboard , i am updating my existing app , i have added a third tabview to the existing 2 tabviews, although i fear that there is a problem somewhere , when i ran the application on the simulator ( iphone,Ipad )+real Ipod is running perfect,but when i run on the Ipad it is only showing 2 tabs , also it is showing some segue errors that is coming when performed on the simulator or on the ipod .

[image: 3tabs as it should be , Ipad is only shown Feeds,shoplog]

Comment: Can you please type segue Errors .

Comment: Your app while running on iPad might be taking reference of previous installed app(from cache). First delete app from iPad and then try again.

Comment: @Alex:Here is the Errors :"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<TestViewController: 0x1dd4b560>) has no segue with identifier '1111''"

Comment: @Piyush: This is was my first guess , i have already tried this also , but was no luck , although i still feel that i am missing something .